# No output from document.write in iFrame in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9, syntax-error

I have this code:

```
if(questionMarker >= 10) //If we've answered 10 questions...
    {
        alert("You have completed the quiz!"); //The quiz is completed
        document.write("Your Answers:"); //Displays their answers
        document.write('<br>' + questionTop[0] + " + " + questionBot[0] + " = " + answers[0] + "  Correct Answer is: " + correct[0]);
        document.write('<br>' + questionTop[1] + " + " + questionBot[1] + " = " + answers[1] + "  Correct Answer is: " + correct[1]);
        document.write('<br>' + questionTop[2] + " + " + questionBot[2] + " = " + answers[2] + "  Correct Answer is: " + correct[2]);
        document.write('<br>' + questionTop[3] + " + " + questionBot[3] + " = " + answers[3] + "  Correct Answer is: " + correct[3]);
        document.write('<br>' + questionTop[4] + " + " + questionBot[4] + " = " + answers[4] + "  Correct Answer is: " + correct[4]);
        document.write('<br>' + questionTop[5] + " + " + questionBot[5] + " = " + answers[5] + "  Correct Answer is: " + correct[5]);
        document.write('<br>' + questionTop[6] + " + " + questionBot[6] + " = " + answers[6] + "  Correct Answer is: " + correct[6]);
        document.write('<br>' + questionTop[7] + " + " + questionBot[7] + " = " + answers[7] + "  Correct Answer is: " + correct[7]);
        document.write('<br>' + questionTop[8] + " + " + questionBot[8] + " = " + answers[8] + "  Correct Answer is: " + correct[8]);
        document.write('<br>' + questionTop[9] + " + " + questionBot[9] + " = " + answers[9] + "  Correct Answer is: " + correct[9]);
        document.write('<br>' + "You got " + correctAnswers + " answers right out of 10."); //Shows how many answers they got right
        document.write('<br>' + "You got " + correctAnswers*10 + "% of the questions right."); //Calculates their percent right
        document.write('<br>' + '<button id="newQuiz" type="button" onclick="window.location.reload()">New Quiz</button>'); //Creates new button to reload the screen and start again
        document.write("</iframe>");
    }
```

And it shows up correctly if I load the page directly. But as an iFrame, the only result I get is "Your Answers:". This is only in IE9, Chrome and FF work acceptably.

The full page is here: http://www.innogeek.com/java/index.html
The iFrame page is here: http://www.innogeek.com/java/frame.html

If you enter 10 answers, it should display your results.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java :)

Comment: You're missing a start iframe tag for sure. Beyond that, don't use `document.write`, there is no reason to do so. why would you want to dynamically create an iframe?

Comment: Please take a look at the links. I added the /iframe as a test and it didn't fix the problem. I should remove it from the question, it doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had a similar problem using IE9 - my test was using a local file so its url started FILE:// this seems to cause problems on IE9.

I switched it round to use `document.body.innerHTML += "Hello IE9";` type code and it works. If i had more time i would have used `createElement` etc.

When the document uses file: protocol document.write seem to really trash the DOM.

you site is using http: and the document.write code appears to work for me, were you testing with file: ?

And the advice from goggling about a bit...don't use `document.write`!